# Numpy/Python performing vs. Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have a simple matrix multiplication code in python (numpy)

```
import numpy as np
import time
a = np.random.random((70000,3000));
b = np.random.random((3000,100));
t1=time.time()
c = np.dot(a,b);
t2=time.time()
print 'Time passed is %2.2f seconds' %(t2-t1
```

It needs about 16 seconds to complete the multiplication (**c = np.dot(a,b);**) on one core. However when I run the same multiplication on Matab, it needs about 1 second on (6 cores) to complete the multiplication.

So, Why Matlab is 2.6 times faster than numpy for matrix multiplication? (The performance per core is important for me)

**UPDATE** I have tried the same thing this time using Eigen. And its performance is slightly better than Matlab. Eigen uses the same Blas implementation as Numpy uses. So the Blas implementation and not be the source of the drawback in the performance.

To make sure that the installed numpy used BLAS, I np.show_config()

```
enter code here
blas_info:
   libraries = ['blas']
   library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
   language = f77
lapack_info:
   libraries = ['lapack']
   library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
   language = f77

atlas_threads_info:
   NOT AVAILABLE

blas_opt_info:
   libraries = ['blas']
   library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
   language = f77
   define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]

atlas_blas_threads_info:
   NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_opt_info:
   libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']
   library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
   language = f77
   define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]

atlas_info:
   NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
   NOT AVAILABLE

blas_mkl_info:
   NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
   NOT AVAILABLE

mkl_info:
   NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: How did you install Numpy? From an Ubuntu package perhaps?

Comment: that blas is reference blas from netlib - the slowest blas around.  install atlas or mkl instead.

Comment: Yes, I used __sudo apt-get install python-numpy__

Comment: @iampat: that's known to be a very suboptimal build of Numpy. Compile it yourself after installing better BLAS libraries, or use [EPD](http://enthought.com/products/epd.php).

Comment: I have tried the same thing this time using Eigen. And its performance is slightly better than Matlab. Eigen uses the same Blas implementation as Numpy uses. So the Blas implementation and not be the source of the drawback in the performance.

Comment: @iampat - Are you sure that Eigen is linking to the same blas implementation?  For example, on my machine, the repo's version of numpy, which links to netlib's blas, takes ~50 seconds. Using EPD, which links to MKL's blas implementation, the calculation takes 0.7 seconds.  The only difference is the blas implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Try out the [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php). For one it is linked to the [Intel Math Kernel Library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/), which is highly optimized and used by MatLab.

Edit: Update for 2017. The [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) is really the way to go these days.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I can not change my python distributions. But, I can the blas implementation .

Comment: I have tried the same thing this time using Eigen. And its performance is slightly better than Matlab. Eigen uses the same Blas implementation as Numpy uses. So the Blas implementation and not be the source of the drawback in the performance.